# replicating a row with changing a field in Python

Tags: csv, python-3.x

I have a large csv file with two columns like this:
**Id**  **and vehicle**

and I like to replicate the rows and if the vehicle is "truck", but instead put "car".
I have this code, but there is an error

which says

```
_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)
```

what does it mean? where I am wrong?

```
infilename = r'external carriers.csv'
outfilename = r'outputCSV.csv'

with open(infilename, 'rb') as fp_in, open(outfilename, 'wb') as fp_out:
    reader = csv.reader(fp_in, delimiter=",")
    writer = csv.writer(fp_out, delimiter=",")
    for row in reader:
        if len(row) == 2:
            if row == "truck":
                writer.writerow = "car"
```

Comment: Can you add the error to your question?and why you check the length of row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's obvious, you have opened the file in text mode you need `rt` :

```
with open(infilename, 'rt') as fp_in, open(outfilename, 'wt') as fp_out:
```

Also if you want to check the vehicle type you need to check the `row[1]` which preserve your car name and then reassign it and write the row to your output file.Also note that you don't need to check the length of your rows since calling the `len` function can be terrible in term if your performance which has O(n) and for large files (specially with large rows) is very inefficient.

```
infilename = r'external carriers.csv'
outfilename = r'outputCSV.csv'

with open(infilename, 'rt') as fp_in, open(outfilename, 'wt') as fp_out:
    reader = csv.reader(fp_in, delimiter=",")
    writer = csv.writer(fp_out, delimiter=",")
    for row1,row2 in reader:
         if row2 == "truck":
            writer.writerow([row1,'car'])
```

Comment: Thank you for that useful hint, but still my output file is empty. Is tehre any other mistake in my code? could you have a look on it again?

Comment: @elnazirannezhad This part writer.writerow = "car"! I didn't saw anything like that so far :).Since `writerow` is a method, you need to pass your row as an argument to it,instead of assigning the row to it!